# On click function does not respond to a wrapped span tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to toggle between an input field and a text field. 
If I do it on just a span tag, then it works fine. However, if a span tag is wrapped as a table data, then it does not respond.

Any help will be appreciated.

**UI**

```
<div>
<table class="students">
      <thead>
          <tr>
              <th>Name</th>
          </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
          <tr>
              <td>
                    <span id ="nameSpan">elvis</span>
                </td>                             
          </tr>
      </tbody>
  </table>  
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var focusInName = '';
    var focusOutName = '';
    $(function () {
        $(document).on("click", ".span", function () {
            focusInName = $(this).html();
            var input = $('<input />', {
                'type': 'text',
                    'name': 'aname',
                    'value': $(this).html(),
                    'class': 'input'
            });

            $(this).parent().append(input);
            $(this).remove();
            input.focus();
            alert(focusInName);
        });

        $(document).on('blur', ".input", function () {
            focusOutName = $(this).val();
            var span = $(
                '<span />', {
                'class': 'span',
                    'html': $(this).val()
            });

            $(this).parent().append(span);
            $(this).remove();        
            alert(focusOutName);
        });
    });
});
```

Fiddle :[HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/c4dac5tj/6/)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/cw6wxwb9/ `<span class='span' id ="nameSpan">elvis</span>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using  [Class Selector (".class")](https://api.jquery.com/class-selector/), You need to add class `span` with span element

```
<span class='span' id ="nameSpan">elvis</span>
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/cw6wxwb9/)

Answer (score 2):

Just remove the dot from the span

```
 $(document).on("click", ".span", function () {
```

to

```
 $(document).on("click", "span", function () {
```

Answer (score 1):

Just remove . from first of span :

```
(document).on("click", "span", function () {
```